# Clearing the mysql database with mysql chmod

Tags: mysql

I have a short URL website that i getting quite popular. I keep statistics of short urls created on the site for every user  up to one year back so they can check visits on their urls.

The database i getting quite big and i wonder how i can clear entry's by running this command every night? i want it to run like chmod but i do not know how i can do that and if it's possible? it yes where and is there somewhere i can do this in WHM / Cpanel or can someone describe how to to it trough SSH? i am familiar with SSH so that's no problem.

```
DELETE FROM `stats` WHERE dt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat:  Check the details before using:

Plan A (On Linux, etc):  Use `cron`

```
0 0 * * * mysql -uuser -ppwd -e 'DELETE FROM mydb.stats WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR'
```

See `mysql_config_editor` for a way to hide the password

Plan B (Windows):  Use `at` and do something similar to `cron`.

(see manual)

Plan C (inside MySQL): set up an `EVENT`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
EVENT `ev5` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2022-08-12'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE DISABLE
    DO 
        DELETE FROM stats WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR
```

Also:  This would be beneficial on `stats`:

```
INDEX(dt)
```

If that would be many thousands of rows in each Delete, `PARTITIONing` would allow for speed:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)  (I would `PARTITION BY RANGE` and use weekly partition and `DROPs`.)

(I don't know what you mean by 'chmod' in this context.)

I think `ssh` could be added to the cron approach if you need to us the 'cron' on a separate machine.

Comment: Thanks! when i enter my username and password it still asks me what database i should use, how do i specify that in the cron?

Comment: @ErissonJ - The db can be specified either as db.tbl in the query or by an extra arg on the mysql commandline.  (I edited to do the former.)  There could be other ommissions/mistakes!